# Rails time formatting test failing because it's one hour off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, factory-bot

I have the following method in one of my Rails classes:

```
def human_departure_time
  "#{departure_time.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")} at #{departure_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")}"
end
```

As you can see, it just takes a `datetime` attribute of the model and formats it so that it is more human friendly.

Anyway, I have the following test for this method:

```
describe "human_departure_time" do
  it "should output the time in readable format" do
    # first I use the Timecop gem to freeze the time
    Timecop.freeze(DateTime.now) do
      bus_time = DateTime.now + 1.days
      # factory a bus with a specific departure time
      bus = Factory :bus, departure_time: bus_time
      expected = "#{bus_time.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")} at #{bus_time.strftime("%I:%M %p")}"
      # check that the output is as expected
      bus.human_departure_time.should == expected
    end
  end
end
```

Pretty simple but the test fails by one hour with the following output:

```
Failures:

  1) Bus human_departure_time should output the time in readable format
     Failure/Error: bus.human_departure_time.should == expected
       expected: "Wednesday, 17 August 2011 at 03:13 AM"
            got: "Wednesday, 17 August 2011 at 02:13 AM" (using ==)
     # ./spec/models/bus_spec.rb:34:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/bus_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is my bus factory just incase that is important. I'm overwriting the departure time with the frozen time plus one hour in my test.

```
factory :bus do
  origin_name "Drogheda"
  event_name "EP"
  departure_time { DateTime.now + 14.days }
end
```

I assume this is something to do with daylight savings time or something? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What does your config/environment.rb timezone show (e.g. mine shows   config.time_zone ='Eastern Time (US & Canada)')?

Comment: It's commented out which means that it defaults to UTC (that's what the comment says). But you're on to something, UTC is one hour behind my local time. But if everything is being set using `DateTime.now` within the same app, how can some times not be UTC?

Comment: What happens if you use `Time.now` rather than `DateTime.now` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord could be automatically converting time attributes in your model to local time.

You can try and use the `%Z` parameter of `strftime` to see the time zone of the outputted timestamp to see where a possible conversion is sneaking into your time.

Some Googled hints that might be relevant:

---

`default_timezone`:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_timezone/class

---

`ActiveRecord::Base.time_zone_aware_attributes`
`config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes`:

http://tamersalama.com/2011/01/10/rails-disable-timezone-conversions/
https://mirrors.kilnhg.com/Repo/Mirrors/From-Git/Rails/History/70cb470c1ab8
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2096919
http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/890711

---

Comment: Yep the deafult_timezone setting was the issue. Thanks.